# DRF not getting ImageField data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to update the post.

```
#urls.py
postdetail = BlogPostDetailView.as_view({
    'get': 'retrieve',
    'put': 'update',
    'patch': 'partial_update',
    'delete': 'destroy'
})
path('<slug>/edit', postdetail, name='postdetail')

#views.py
class BlogPostDetailView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     queryset = BlogPost.objects.order_by('-date_created')
     serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer
     lookup_field = 'slug'
     permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )

#serializers.py
class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = BlogPost
    fields = ('id', 'title', 'slug', 'category', 'thumbnail',
              'content', 'date_created', 'author')
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

when I go to url to update a post, it shows thumbnail field empty " No file selected". Why it is not showing anything in thumbnail?

[image: Imagefield]

Answer (score 0):

The `ImageField` receives a file via the request, creates a static file in the server, and stores in the DB a reference to it. When you retrieve the item that has the `ImageField`, it should return a url to the file, i.e.: `http://my-server.com/static/some_file.jpg`.
So in your form, you should display that in an `img` tag to see the current image, having also the upload form field in case the user wants to update it.

Comment: It means I can't test my api endpoint using http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/blog/create/  and it will work fine in frontend like react

Comment: I don't understand you. I was answering the question about why you weren't seeing anything on an update, assuming you loaded the data you previously retrieved